# Incorrect output when printing diamond using do while loop

Tags: java

I am creating code to print a diamond using only Do while loops and I have got the following code:

```
public static void diamond3() {
System.out.println("Output for: Do while Loop");

int noOfRows = DIAMOND_SIZE;

//Getting midRow of the diamond
int midRow = (noOfRows)/2;

//Initializing row with 1
int row = 1;

int i = midRow;

do {
    //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
    int j = 1;
    do {
        System.out.print(" ");
        j++;
}
    while (j <= i);


    //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
    j = 1;
    do {
        System.out.print("* ");
        j++;
    }
    while (j <= row);
    System.out.println();

    //Incrementing the row
    row++;

    i--;
}  
while (i > 0);

i = 0;

do { 
    //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
    int j = 1;
    do {
        System.out.print(" ");
        j++;
    }
    while (j <= i);

    //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
    int mid = (row+1)/2;
    j = row;
    do {
        if(i==0 && j==mid) 
            System.out.print("o ");

        else 
            System.out.print("* ");
            j--;
    }
    while (j > 0);
    System.out.println();

    //Decrementing the row
    row--;
    i++;
}

while(i <= midRow);
}
```

Im meant to get a diamond shape but I am getting the following shape:

```
 * 
 * * 
 * o * 
 * * 
  *
```

The expected out is:

```
    * 
  * * * 
* * o * *
  * * * 
    *
```

Can someone help figure out where I have gone wrong. I have checked the code so many times but unable to figure out where the mistake is.

Comment: what is your expected output? Show an example so we don't have to guess.

Comment: have you tried to debug the code with a debugger? that helps a lot to reproduce the logic and I am sure you find the bug very quickly.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug by hand.  Print out the program and walk through the steps one at a time while keeping track of the values in the variables.  Don't skip anything.  You will most likely understand why you get the output you get.  Then the fix is most likely clear to you as well.

Comment: I have edited the post and included the expected outcome. @MichaelMarkidis

Comment: @donk2017 Try to figure it out by yourself first. You will level up if you can spot your own mistakes.

Comment: Somebody literally asked this same question with the diamond a day or two ago.  lol.  Is this a homework assignment or a project on the internet?

Comment: @user3437460 I have tried several timed to figure out what the problem is and tried changing a few things but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach to this question:

```
public static void diamond3() {
System.out.println("Output for: Do while Loop");

    int noOfRows =5;
    int md=noOfRows%2;

    //Getting midRow of the diamond
    int midRow = (noOfRows)/2;      

    int i = noOfRows;

    do {
        //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row

        int j = 1;
        do {
            if (i-md==0) break; 
            System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
    }
        while (j <= i-md);

        //Printing j *'s at the end of each row

        do {
            if (i-md==0 && j==midRow+1){
              System.out.print("o ");   
            } else {
              System.out.print("* ");
            }
            j++;
        }
        while (j <= (noOfRows+1-md));
        System.out.println();


        i=(i - 2);
    }  
    while (i >= 0); 

    i = 2;

    do {
        //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row

        int j = 1;
        do {
              System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
        }
        while (j <= i);     

        do {
            System.out.print("* ");
            j++;
        }
        while (j <= (noOfRows+1-md));

        System.out.println();

        //Printing j *'s at the end of each row

        i=(i + 2);
    }  
    while (i <=noOfRows);
}
```

Comment: Thats ok but theres a few problems, see the answer below.

Comment: How would you do the same thing but with just For loops?

Comment: I have tried to convert it to fully For loops but doesn't give the desired output. See the answer below.

Comment: Try to think a bit its actually easy to convert while you have the original answer